# WebView click item <button> in HTML

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm developing a simple app and I'm new to Android. I have a page on the Google server with `<button>` elements in HTML. These elements don't have the `id` attribute, so I can't use `getElementsById`.

Here's my code but it doesn't work. Why? Why I can't simulate clicks programmatically?

```
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("google server here");

    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('button')[21].click();");
        }
    });
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('button')[21]` selects the 22nd `<button>` element on the page. Are you certain that's the right one?

Comment: yes, it is. There must be a click emulation, right?